# how to sum arrays of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I know we can sum the array elements using `reduce()` but what if we have an array of arrays. For eg:

```
var result=[10,20,30];
result.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

it will return `60`

but if we have

```js
result=[
  [10,20,30],
  [20,30,40],
  [60,70,80]
]
console.log(result);
```

how can we get the final result as `result=[60,90,210]` using reduce?

Comment: It seems to me that you want to **mutate** the `result` array. In that case, do: `result.forEach(function(d, i, arr) { arr[i] = d.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fisrt you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and inside map use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
result=[
  [10,20,30],
  [20,30,40],
  [60,70,80]
  ]
const final = result.map(item => item.reduce((a, b)=> a + b, 0))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through each of the subarrays in the outer array. The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Once you get a subarray, follow the previous approach to find the sum using reduce().

```
result = result.map(subArray => subArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.reduce` only, I suggest this code:

```
 result=[
  [10,20,30],
  [20,30,40],
  [60,70,80]
]
const sum = result.reduce((a, b) => {
  return [...a.concat(b.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))]
}, [])
console.log(sum)
```